how to initial and align 2D models with Viewer3D.js (JavaScript)
Although I am not yet familiar with the Viewer3D.js (version 7), we are exploring the possibility of using the APS Viewer API to meet customer needs.
We need to display multiple 2D drawings together in one viewer, and I know we can use Aggregated View API to achieve this.
When I load two 2D drawings in, they will be displayed in the middle of the viewport and fill the viewport.
But this brings about the following three issues.

The positions of the baseline lines X0, X1, X2, Y0, Y1, etc. in the two drawings are misaligned  and I need to align them.

one of the 2D drawings has become larger than the original drawing, the distance between the reference lines X0 and X2 has become 943.8. I need to adjust it to the correct value of 910.0

It seems that the units on the drawings have changed to inches("). I need to adjust the units to centimeters (mm).


Here's the image, only part of the drawings, but I think it should illustrate the problem.
image
Below is my initial code:
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {
        //initialize the viewer object
        const viewerDiv = document.getElementById("AutodeskViewer");
        const view = new Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView();
        view.init(viewerDiv);

        const tasks = [];
        UrnArr.forEach(md => tasks.push(loadManifest("urn:"+md)));

        Promise.all(tasks)
            .then(docs => Promise.resolve(docs.map(doc => {
                const bubbles = doc.getRoot().search({ type: 'geometry', role: '2d' });
                const bubble = bubbles[0];
                if (!bubble) return null;

                return bubble;
            })))
            .then(bubbles => {
                view.setNodes(bubbles);
                view.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.DocumentBrowser');
                viewer = view;
            });
    });

Can Viewer3D.js solve the above three issues?
If you have any solutions or related blog posts, please give them to me. I shall be grateful.
I tried to change the camera, but it affects all 2d models. I think I should manipulate the geometries in models, but how to do that.

I know the reason of issue No.3. my origin DXF file didn't contain drawing units information. I set drawing units info($INSUNITS) to DXF file header and it's normally shown in millimeter by forge viewer.

After I set options.placementTransform as new THREE.Matrix4().scale(new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)).setPosition({x:1,y:1,z:0}) when loads model, I can change the position of model. But the model makes a large offset although I set x:1, y:1. How can I control the position of model more precisely. Thank you.
